# Finding unique query values when using Django/Python

Tags: python, django, unique

I'm trying to print out a page with all the available categories of an auction site on it. Right now it's printing out every instance of whats in the table. For instance, there are multiple print outs of "Animals" as a category - but I just want it to show one.

What's the best way to do this?
I tried the "distinct" method but it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Below is my relevant code:

views.py:

```
def categories(request):
    query = NewPost.objects.all().distinct()
    return render(request, "auctions/categories.html", { "queries": query })
```

categories.html:

```
{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <h2>Categories</h2>
    {% for query in queries %}
        <li><a href="/categories/{{ query.category }}">{{ query.category }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}  
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: In your code [`.distinct()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) will show all rows because each row contains the PK of the row, so by definition all rows are different.

Comment: ooo so if i did a filter(category = category).distinct() then it should be good?

Comment: query = NewPost.objects.values("category").distinct()    <--- that worked!

Answer (score 1):

Can you give us the models.py code for `NewPost`. You probably want to query the `Category` model (if you have one) to get a unique list of Categories.

Comment: class NewPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    category = models.CharField(max_length=64)

Comment: i don't have category model...it's part of the newpost model when a user makes a new auction post.

Comment: It might make sense to have a separate `Category` model and then the `category` field in your `New Post` model can be a [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) pointing to the `Category` model. You can still allow users to create new categories when they create new auctions posts.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm going with the option of letting users create their own categories for now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

query = NewPost.objects.values("category").distinct()

Will find a distinct column value.  Thanks guys!